# Who ordained Hillel and Shammai?

Tags: semicha, hillel

Who ordained Hillel and Shammai?

I have searched but have been unable to find any indication of who gave them semicha/ordination.

It's clear in the mishna that they received the tradition from the pair/zugot that preceded them, that's Shmaya and Avtalyon, but that doesn't say from whom they received semicha/ordination.

Comment: could whoever downvoted my question please comment on why?

Comment: one anonymous downvote is only a side effect.

Comment: It's extremely rare to know who gave semikha to whom. Why would you expect we might know in this case? And why do you want to know? Please edit to clarify. Important info should be in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Pirkei Avos Chapter 1:10--12:

> א,י  שמעיה ואבטליון קיבלו מהם.  שמעיה אומר, אהוב את המלאכה, ושנוא את הרבנות; ואל תתוודע לרשות.&rim;
>
> א,יא  אבטליון אומר, חכמים, היזהרו בדבריכם--שמא תחובו חובת גלות, ותגלו למקום המים הרעים, וישתו התלמידים הבאים אחריכם וימותו, ונמצא שם שמיים מתחלל.‏
>
> א,יב  הלל ושמאי קיבלו מהם.‏

**Shamaya and Avtalyon** received [the tradition] from [their teachers] ... *Hillel and Shammai received it from them.*

Similarly the Rambam writes in his [introduction to the Yad HaChazaka](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/00.htm) (paragraph 8):

> שמעיה ואבטליון גרי הצדק ובית דינם קיבלו מיהודה ושמעון ובית דינם.  והילל ושמאי ובית דינם קיבלו משמעיה ואבטליון ובית דינם.
>
> Shamaya and Avtalyon, the righteous converts, and their court, received from Yehudah, Shimon, and their court; and Hillel, Shammai, and their court received from Shamaya, Avtalyon, and their court.

In the discussion about rebooting real ordination today, it is observed that Eliyahu the Prophet could descend from the heavens anytime and grant someone real *semicha*; how do we know he has it? "Because the Rambam's introduction lists him on the chain as receiving it from Achiyah HaShiloni."

Comment: Are you equating Torah with s'micha? Can you provide sources that show that what was passed down from Moshe to Yehoshua to the Z'keinim etc was s'micha?

Comment: shmaya and avtalyon were the zugot before hillel(the elder) and shammai https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugot#List_of_zugot  but that doesn't mean that either of them gave semicha to hillel(the elder), and shammai

Comment: This answer is right, the zugot were Nasi and Av Bet din. Despite that Shmaya and Avtalion were Gerim. I don't remember, but A gemara adresses this.

Comment: @kouty  Who gives Smicha, the Nasi, or the Av Bet Din, or either? And which one are you saying  gave him Smicha? Shmaya, or Avtalyon?

Answer (score -2):

When the Romans destroyed the Second Temple in 70 C.E., Yochanan ben Zaccai preserved Judaism by substituting the synagogue for the Temple and prayers for sacrifices. Then, Rabbi Akiva further preserved Judaism. Before Yochanan ben Zakkai, no one was called rabbis. Hillel had no title, and neither did the sages of the Mishnah Pirke Avot. It follows that Shmuley Boteach, in his book Kosher Jesus where he calls Jesus “Rabbi Jesus” is mistaken because while the Pharisees preceded the rabbis, the institution of rabbis began approximately 70 C.E, when the temple was destroyed.

The idea of a rabbi who is “ordained”, semicha institution was abolished by the Romans in the year 415 of the Common Era, and yet the idea of semicha persists, which indicates that the institution was reinstituted. But there were no rabbis or semichas before Rabbi Akiva’s time. Thus, no one “ordained”, semicha Hillel or Shammai but they are still great sages of Judaism.

Comment: I don’t really understand this answer. Are you saying that there couldn’t have been semicha because no one was called “Rabbi”?

Comment: The institution of rabbis did not exist before 70 C.E., when the system of  “ordained”, semicha began.

Comment: I don’t see anything in the question about the institution of rabbis. I see a question about who gave specific people semicha. If your answer is that there was no such thing as semicha, then that’s exactly what your answer should say, preferably with supporting evidence.

Comment: @Alex His answer does say that there was no smicha therefore they weren't ordained... it'd be good if he provided some evidence.. but I have heard the idea he has mentioned, it's not way out there. It's hard to find evidence of smicha at that time. (and that does answer the question) I notice this answer fades when not hovering over it.. I hope he didn't delete the answer as it is a useful answer, he should undelete it. I just wonder how well it can be backed up

Comment: @TurkHill i'm not even sure if Yochanan Ben Zakkai had the title Rabbi.(like rabee/רבי  in the gemara).  He had the title Rabban, which is aramaic for "my master", and was a title normally given to the nasi on a sanhedrin eg rabban gamliel I and rabban gamliel II.  I'm also not sure with these titles of rabban if any are retroactively put in. I'm aware that רבי doesn't occur in the mishna. The closest is aseh lecha rav. Do we know that the title of רבי(my master in hebrew and aramaic), in the gemara, implies semicha?

Comment: @barlop He does say it, but it’s kind of buried in the discussion about rabbis and Jesus, and no evidence is provided. Semicha is mentioned in the Talmud (e.g. Avoda Zara 8b), so at the very least an answer claiming that there was no semicha should address that

Comment: @barlop That you for your comments. I don't think רבי refers to semicha as the institution of rabbis began late, after the destruction of the Second temple in 70 C.E.. It is possible that the gemara implies semicha like other meanings of words change over the years, but I am skeptical.

Comment: @TurkHill  I figured the mishna might be around second temple time, (before? after? ), and the gemara was quite a bit after the second temple was destroyed?  what are the date ranges for the mishna, and for the gemara?    and since I figured that the gemara may be after the second temple,  I figured maybe semicha had been developed by then or around then.  And can you address the claim from commenter alex "Semicha is mentioned in the Talmud (e.g. Avoda Zara 8b)"

Comment: @barlop The Mishnah was edited in the third century, Targum Onkelos is 400 CE. The Gemara definitely was compiled after the destruction of the temple. We know the Babylonian Talmud was comprised mainly of Aramaic and the Jerusalem Talmud was both in Hebrew and Aramaic. The Talmud was written over a wide period of time, spanning for generations.

Comment: We also know that Rav Ashi edited the Talmud, and that the Jerusalem Talmud was edited in the fourth century. Thus, it is likely that the Talmud is referring to semicha at a later date. The talmud often drags rabbis generations apart and places them in one sitting, as if they are holding a discussion that could not have happened.

Comment: @TurkHill  so is the term רבי used for sages in the talmud before 70CE?  And, for the idea that semicha came after 70CE, it seems you aren't basing it on the term רבי 'cos you seem to suggest that רבי might not imply semicha.. So on what do you base the idea that semicha only developed after 70CE?    How do you know that Akiva or Yochanan Ben Zakkai instituted it? How do you know that mention of semicha is only the result of 4th century editing, and not in there from before? would you say that רבי doesn't necessarily mean semicha, but the lack of the title רבי does indicate no semicha?

Comment: @barlop The term Moshe Rabbenu is popular but Moses was not a rabbi. The Pharisees (320 BCE-70 CE) were followed by the rabbis. The name Pharisees is from the root p-r-sh, and means those who “separated.” When the rabbis succeeded the Pharisees in 70 CE, Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai was the spiritual leader and he revived Judaism after 70 C.E..

Comment: Amongst much else, he replaced the temple and sacrifices with the synagogue and prayer. He also, in place of kohanim, “priests,” inaugurated the idea of rabbis, meaning the teachers of the people. Thus was the first rabbinate instituted. He then assumed the title “rabban” for himself, a term that indicates the leading rabbi. However, the religious scholars before him weren’t called rabbi.

Comment: Hillel had no title; and the practice of ordination, in Hebrew it is semicha, ceased for a time in the year 415 when the Romans abolished its functions. But this did not last and the semicha was never fully abolished. Now the term רבי could have been used in the Talmud in which it would mean teacher but I would think the practice of ordination if we are talking before Zakkai's time, did not exist. Hillel, as far as I know, is never called רבי. It follows, that Zakkai began the institution.

Comment: Since the Talmud is silent when referring to Hillel as רבי, as far as I can tell, then it appears that Zakkai, as the consensus indicates, was the first to apply the term in a practical way or at least in a more universal way. Now if the Talmud mentions רבי before his time, it could be speaking of teachers in general, but I would not think the practice of semicha existed then. And even then, I think the Talmud was edited when it mentions רבי. Why couldn't they be called sages?

Comment: @TurkHill from what I understand, rabban means the head of a sanhedrin.. and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin   Rabban Yochanan Ben Zakkai was the head from the years 70-80.     According to this article though he might not have been the nasi, and wasn't a kohen or levi https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/johanan-ben-zakkai/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101972/discussion-between-barlop-and-turk-hill).